# Tornado Url Not Match with ? ("Interrogation") Sign

Tags: python, regex, tornado

I'm using tornado to create a web service. I learn many ways to handle URLs but i can't find a way to handle this URLS:

> Main-Dns:xxxx(port)/{System}(this is static)/{word}?q={word}

My code:

```
 import tornado.ioloop 
 import tornado.web
 import psycopg2
 import json
 import collections
 import datetime
 import decimal


 application = tornado.web.Application([

 (r"/system/(\w+)[?][q]=[\w+]",MainHandler),

 ])

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     application.listen(8888)
     tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I tried many regex only when i erase the '?' it works

for example for this URLs get the uri:

```
uri:/system/4?q=
handler:r"/system/(\d)[?]q=",MainHandler

uri:/system/word_word?q=
handler:r"/system/(\w+)[?][q]=",MainHandler
```

The parameter is optional i only put the "()" to test sending parameter.

I used Python regex tester web, and find that i worked but in Tornado i think it's not the same thing.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: more examples

```
   Handle:/system/(\w+)[?]q=(\w+)
   URL examples : /system/(any_word)?q=(any_word) like
                  /system/word_word?q=word
                  /system/wo5d_w5rd?q=w5ord
```

Edit: This is the console output:

```
             WARNING:tornado.access:404  GET/system/test?q=test
```

I can do without the '?' but i need to do it with the '?'.

Edit: With method get_argument(), it's something like this posible:

```
       Uri:/system/word?{last_name='Jackson_Smith'}  
       to get this parameters: "word" , "last_name" , "'Jackson_Smith'"
```

Comment: Can you show a few examples of URLs and expected output?

Comment: >some examples >handle:/system/(\w+)[?]q=(\w+)                                    >url:/system/word_word?q=word , /system/word_4d?q=44d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to try to capture the "?q=.." in the regular expression. You capture that in the `RequestHandler` itself, using the `get_argument` method.

Here's a small example that I think captures what you're trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, word=None):
        self.write("word is %s\n" % word)
        self.write("uri is %s\n" % self.request.uri)
        self.write("q is %s\n" % self.get_argument("q"))


application = tornado.web.Application([

(r"/system/(.+)",MainHandler),

])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Here's sample output:

```
dan@dan:~$ curl localhost:8888/system/4?q=44d
word is 4
uri is /system/4?q=44d
q is 44d
dan@dan:~$ curl localhost:8888/system/word_word?q=word
word is word_word
uri is /system/word_word?q=word
q is word
dan@dan:~$ curl localhost:8888/system/wo5d_w5rd?q=w5ord
word is wo5d_w5rd
uri is /system/wo5d_w5rd?q=w5ord
q is w5ord
```

Comment: Yes i want to capture other arguments however i get http:404 error because tornado whenever i put '?' the handler can't match the Uri.

Comment: Can you provide a URI that my sample code not handle?

Comment: How can i use that method with a URL like this: /system/word_word?q={last_name:'Jackson_Smith'}, i like to capture "word_word","last_name" and "'Jackson_Smith'". Without ""

Comment: If you're going to try to send JSON, you're probably going to need to use a POST request with the JSON in the body, rather than a GET. The code I provided can handle that request, but you lose the curly brackets. It just ends up receiving this `q is last_name:'Jackson_Smith'`. This is because that's what Tornado ends up with in the uri itself: `uri is /system/word_word?q=last_name:'Jackson_Smith'`

Comment: ok thanks for the help, i will try to do it from another way.

Comment: Actually, JSON in the url arguments can be handled if it's escaped properly: Using this uri `/system/word_word?q=%7B%22last_name%22%3A%22Jackson_Smith%22%7D` Results in the json being received intact: `q is {"last_name":"Jackson_Smith"}`

Comment: i will try that, when i put in the URL "{}" it changes to %7B,%7D but with the '?' i don't change.